# Another iptables/ipset issue where connections are not being blocked

Tags: iptables, ipset

The listing at the bottom of this question is the output from "iptables-save" on my Debian system.

I set up an ipset list called "manual-block" to contain addresses of connections that I want to block. However, it seems that some (maybe all?) of the connections from addresses in the "manual-block" ipset list are being accepted.

For example, `ipset list manual-block | egrep '^77\.90\.185\.59$'` gives "77.90.185.59" as output, but I keep getting many connections from 77.90.185.59. This also occurs with other IP addresses that are in the "manual-block" ipset list.

I have rebooted and reinitialized all my iptables/ipset rules and lists, but connections from those IP addresses in my "manual-block" ipset list are still getting through.

When I created these rules, I did `iptables -I INPUT ...` in all cases, although they are listed here as `-A INPUT ...` . Is that correct, and if not, could that be the reason for these rules not working?

In any case, I'm at a loss as to what to do in order to get these rules to start working.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions and ideas.

**PS**: These are the commands I use for generating the entries for the manual-block rules ...

```
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -i eth+ -m set --match-set manual-block src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-net-unreachable

/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -i eth+ -m set --match-set manual-block src -j DROP
```

This is the iptables-save output ...

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Oct 11 17:56:59 2023
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [88:12650]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [83:12488]
-A INPUT -i eth+ -m set --match-set manual-block src -j DROP
-A INPUT -i eth+ -m set --match-set manual-block src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-net-unreachable
-A INPUT -i eth+ -m set --match-set cc-block src -j DROP
-A INPUT -i eth+ -p tcp -m multiport --dports 110,143,993,995 -m set --match-set imap-allow src -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth+ -p tcp -m multiport --dports 110,143,993,995 -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 11 17:56:59 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Oct 11 17:56:59 2023
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [78240:9303925]
:INPUT ACCEPT [78217:9302721]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [66186:11564488]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [66186:11564488]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 11 17:56:59 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Oct 11 17:56:59 2023
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 11 17:56:59 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Oct 11 17:56:59 2023
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [78240:9303925]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [66186:11564488]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 11 17:56:59 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Oct 11 17:56:59 2023
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [65863:8462327]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [66187:11564616]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 11 17:56:59 2023
```

Comment: Are your NIC interfaces actually named using the `eth0` , `eth1` etc. convention  and not using bus derived predictable names like eno1, wlp1s3 ? Because otherwise they won’t match with `-i eth+`

Comment: Yes, the interface is indeed named "eth0", and it hosts 3 "inet" IPv4 addresses and 3 corresponding "inet6" IPv6 addresses. The "ip addresses" command also shows other interfaces that have no IP's associated with them, and that are all marked as "DOWN" :   dummy0, teql0, tunl0@NONE, gre0@NONE, gretap0@NONE, erspan0@NONE, ip_vti0@NONE, ip6_vti0@NONE, sit0@NONE, ip6tnl0@NONE, and ip6gre0@NONE. And there's the "lo" interface on 127.0.0.1/8 and its corresponding inet6 ::1/128

Comment: I'm guessing that the presence of "-A INPUT" in the iptables-save output is indicating the problem. Even though I always do "iptables -I INPUT ...", the rule gets listed as "-A INPUT". I think, therefore, that the rules are being taken as "-A INPUT" and are prioritized in reverse order from how they are listed, and that this means that one of the later "ACCEPT" rules takes precedence over the "manual-block" rule.  I'm checking this now.

Comment: `iptables-save` preserves the current ordering of your rules ; restoring with `iptables-restore` by default flushes a chain of all existing rules assuring a clean slate and will return your effective firewall configuration with the rules in the  correct order

Comment: But iptables-save shows my rules prefixed with `-A`, even though I entered them with `-I` . Is that correct?

Comment: A clean chain flushed with `iptables -F` followed by  `iptables -I rule 2` followed by `iptables -I rule 1` is the same as `iptables -F` followed by `iptables -A rule 1` followed by `iptables -A rule 2` so yes that is correct

Comment: Yes, I understand about the `-I` ordering versus the `-A` ordering. I just was worried that the output of iptables-save used `-A`, even though I entered the rules in the reverse order with `-I`. But I guess that's not a problem.